# Invalid value for field 'instance.networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP': The specified external IP address is not reserved in region

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

when I'm running the command:

```
gcloud beta compute instance-groups managed rolling-action start-update gke-playground-pool-test-1-420d5b80-grp  --version template=elk-pool-template-us-west1-3 --zone us-west1-b --max-surge 1 --max-unavailable 1 --type opportunistic --force
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.instance-groups.managed.rolling-action.start-update) Could not fetch resource:
 - Invalid value for field 'resource.instanceTemplate': ''. Unable to create an instance from instanceTemplate elk-pool-template-us-west1-3 in zone us-west1-b:
        Invalid value for field 'instance.networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP': The specified external IP address 'xx.xxx.xxx.xx' is not reserved in region 'us-west1'.
```

Comment: Could it be that you're trying to claim External IPs via your templates that you haven't reserved? If so, it's probable that the IPs your template includes aren't currently available. Corrollary: if you wish to reuse IP addresses, you must reserve  (and pay for) them. Then, as long as you don't use them elsewhere, they'll be available. Otherwise, you must take whatever External IP the service allocates to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The specified external IP address 'xx.xxx.xxx.xx' is not reserved in 
>   region 'us-west1'

The issue you have described is usually caused by a template that tries to claim unreserved External IP. To make those IP's available you have to first reserve them by buying it in GCP. You can find more about External IP addresses [here.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/)

If the reserved IP address is available, you can use it. In another case, the service will allocate External IP which will be available at that moment. You can find more about reserving IP addresses [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address).

Comment: Thanks it was solved by changing the static IP configuration under network at the template edit to ephemeral IP without a hardcoded one.